# Nodejs builder class function is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have a custom class using Node JS builder to create a class with variables that may or may not be present and a custom function in order to validate equality (Overriding the default `equals` nodejs function) This class is being used for business purposes so all actual data has been obfuscated.

***Class***

```
module.exports = class User {
  constructor() {
    this.title = '';
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.email = '';
    this.emailConfirmation = '';
    this.password = '';
    this.passwordConfirmation = '';
    this.addressLine1 = '';
    this.addressLine2 = '';
    this.town = '';
    this.postcode = '';
    this.customerToken = '';
    this.businessOwner = '';
    this.authToken = '';
    this.subscriptionsCount = '';
  }
  equals(jsonObject) {
    return (jsonObject.title === this.title && jsonObject.firstName === this.firstName && jsonObject.lastName === this.lastName && jsonObject.email === this.email
        && jsonObject.addressLine1 === this.addressLine1 && jsonObject.town === this.town && jsonObject.postcode === this.postcode)
  }
  createUserObject() {
    return {
      withTitle: function (n) {
        this.title = n;
        return this
      },
      withFirstName: function (n) {
        this.firstName = n;
        return this
      },
      withLastName: function (n) {
        this.lastName = n;
        return this
      },
      withEMail: function (n) {
        this.email = n;
        return this;
      },
      withEMailConfirmation: function (n) {
        this.emailConfirmation = n;
        return this;
      },
      withPassword: function (n) {
        this.password = n;
        return this;
      },
      withPasswordConfirmation: function (n) {
        this.passwordConfirmation = n;
        return this;
      },
      withAddressLine1: function (n) {
        this.addressLine1 = n;
        return this;
      },
      withAddressLine2: function (n) {
        this.addressLine2 = n;
        return this;
      },
      withTown: function (n) {
        this.town = n;
        return this;
      },
      withPostCode: function (n) {
        this.postCode = n;
        return this;
      },
      withAuthToken: function (n) {
        this.authToken = n;
        return this;
      },
      withBusinessOwner: function (n) {
        this.businessOwner = n;
        return this;
      },
      withCustomerToken: function (n) {
        this.customerToken = n;
        return this;
      },
      withSubscriptionsCount: function (n) {
        this.subscriptionsCount = n;
        return this;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I am calling my custom class using the `new` keyword, so it should instantiate a new class and then I am trying to call the `equals` function as described above with the below:

***Code***

```
var myUser = new User();

myUser = myUser.createUserObject().withTitle([DATA]).withFirstName([DATA])
.withLastName([DATA]).withEMail([DATA]).withAddressLine1([DATA])
.withAddressLine2([DATA]).withTown([DATA]).withPostCode([DATA])
.withAuthToken([DATA]).withBusinessOwner([DATA])
.withCustomerToken([DATA]).withSubscriptionsCount([DATA]);

if(myUser.equals([VALIDATION-DATA])) {
  SOME ACTION HERE
}
else {
  SOME OTHER ACTION HERE, THROW ERROR
}
```

My output is through the terminal window and as such tells me that `myUser.equals is not a function` as shown below:

***Terminal***

```
(node:8376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: myUser.equals is not a function
at HttpRequest.get.then (/Users/sam.levene/projects/public_api_tests/custom_classes/ApiServices.js:40:28)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:8376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8376) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've really tripped yourself up here with the context object (`this`).

I don't think what you're doing here is really the best way to do it. Basically once you create that object

```
return {
    withTitle: function (n) {
        this.title = n;
        return this
    },
```

You're creating a new context. That's why `equals` is undefined. If you `console.log(this, this.equals)` inside one of those setters you'll see what I mean.

The better way to do this would be something like:

```
class UserFactory
    getInstance({ title, firstname, lastname, ... })
```

and a User class that implements `equals`

```
class User
    constructor({ title, firstname, lastname, ... })
    equals()
```

Comment: Can you expand on your suggestion?

Comment: What do you want to know

Comment: How does the User class and UserFactory interface?

Comment: The factory creates instances of the user. Honestly though seems unnecessary unless you want to be having different types of users down the line. Do you have a real use case for this? Otherwise just instantiate users directly ie. `new User({ firstname, lastname, email })`.  Then your `equals` method will be comparing `this.firstname` with `otherUser.firstname` and it will just work.

Comment: I see, so a kind of class within a class; gotcha. I'll have a look at trying this out on Monday. Sadly; I can't showcase real use-cases due to work-related restrictions, but I'll let you know if your suggestion worked.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found another way of doing it that met my criteria. I may self-answer this soon.